# iOS bad frame size with size classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, storyboard, size-classes

I'm using xCode 6 and sizes classes for my app.

I'm meeting a very strange problem I don't understand.

I've a UIView which constraints in a UIViewController, I set a width constraint for Any x Any (150x150) size classe, and another widh constraint for Regular x Regular (300x300).

When I log the size of my UIView, when the app is running on iPad, I meet a problem.

Indeed, in "viewWillAppear" ,"viewWillLayoutSubviews" or "viewDidLayoutSubviews" I get the size "150x150" instead of "300x300".

My logs :

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear Size %f - %f",         
    self.myView.frame.size.width, self.myView.frame.size.height);
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear Size %f - %f",     
   self.myView.frame.size.width, self.myView.frame.size.height);
  }

 - (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews {
     [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
     NSLog(@"viewWillLayoutSubviews Size %f - %f",   
     self.myView.frame.size.width, self.myView.frame.size.height);
 }

 - (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
     [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
     NSLog(@"viewDidLayoutSubviews Size %f - %f",     
     self.myView.frame.size.width, self.myView.frame.size.height);
 }
```

The thing I don't understand it's that, the logs shows :

```
2015-02-17 09:29:38.984 myApp[660:42565] viewDidLoad Size   
150.000000 - 150.000000

2015-02-17 09:29:38.985 myApp[660:42565] viewWillAppear Size    
150.000000 - 150.000000

2015-02-17 09:29:39.047 myApp[660:42565] viewWillLayoutSubviews 
Size 150.000000 - 150.000000

2015-02-17 09:29:39.058 myApp[660:42565] viewDidLayoutSubviews 
Size 150.000000 - 150.000000

2015-02-17 09:29:39.063 myApp[660:42565] viewWillLayoutSubviews  
Size 230.000000 - 230.000000

2015-02-17 09:29:39.063 myApp[660:42565] viewDidLayoutSubviews 
Size 230.000000 - 230.000000

2015-02-17 09:29:39.586 myApp[660:42565] viewDidAppear Size 
230.000000 - 230.000000

2015-02-17 09:29:39.591 myApp[660:42565] viewWillLayoutSubviews 
Size 230.000000 - 230.000000

2015-02-17 09:29:39.593 myApp[660:42565] viewDidLayoutSubviews  
Size 230.000000 - 230.000000
```

So what's happening ? Why the first time I get the size of the Any x Any size class ? And Why these method are called many times ?

I see I've the correct frame size in viewDidAppear, but I don't like it because there is a delay beforc this function is called. (I need to do something with the frame size of my view before to show it....)

Comment: `size` is not a class. Your issue is related to constraints, not to the size struct.

Comment: @Hermann I don't think he meant the `UIView`s `size` property as an instance of a Class but merely used it for debug purposes, and the question is related to the `size classes` as there're at least two of them setup at IB and they aren't working as expected.

Comment: @A-Live, now that you are mentioning it ...

Comment: Yes i'm talking about size classes.

Answer (score 1):

The "temporary" (but beautiful bullshit :D) solution :

In viewDidLoad I added :

```
if(UIDEVICE == IPAD) {
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

With that, I've the correct frame size, but I want to understand what is the problem with my code, size classes, etc... :(

Comment: At the end, this was my solution for my Custom UIImageView, using size classes, here it's my [code](http://pastie.org/9965848). And it's working. **But as you says, it will be nice to have an explanation why in some methods we get the Any Any size class value.** And I didn't have to call the method layoutIfNeeded :)

Comment: news about this problem ? :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize UIView according to Auto Layout before `- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` Try below way.

```
    - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [self.myView layoutIfNeeded];

        NSLog(@"viewWillAppear Size %f - %f",         
        self.myView.frame.size.width, self.myView.frame.size.height);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this :    

     if(UIDEVICE == IPAD) {
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
     }

but I think it's not "normal" to have to do that...